# How to write if condition for empty tuple in swift?

Tags: swift, return, tuples, is-empty

I am stuck with if condition for this type of function return - `([(Range<String.Index>, Range<String.Index>)](), [(Range<String.Index>, Range<String.Index>)]())`. I have function N1 returning this empty tuple in a certain condition. Then, in another function I need to check if the function N1 is returning this empty tuple. How can I write such if-condition if this return is true, i.e. this tuple is empty ?

```
If returnOfFunction == ...
{
    do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply check

```
if returnOfFunction.0.isEmpty && returnOfFunction.1.isEmpty
```

Comment: Thanks, Great! It is simple as it should be!